# how to add Previous date with new date in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to Calculate How many Hours per Day Employee Working in Company. 
I Am Using MySQL Server .

```
   Date             From     To         Total_Time    Working_Hours/day  
   -----           -----    -------        -----       -------
  23-12-2014       2:00       3:00         1:00         
  24-12-2014       8:00       9:00         1:00           1:00
  23-12-2014       5:00       6:30         2:30      
  23-12-2014       7:00       8:00         3:30           3:30
```

Finally I want only  Working_Hours/day

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysqlfunctions for what you're trying to achieve

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('2007-12-31 10:02:00','2007-12-30 12:01:01') * 24*60*60;
-- result: 19013097600.000000 the difference in seconds for days.
```

This leaves you with recalculating the second to hours and so on, that's why i'd recommend writing a script for this kind of task.

Also you should always use a timeformat for times, as this is something you shouldn't calculate time with only laymans knowledge about time.

Comment: i Have Used TIMEDIFF for Total_Time  field but i want take finaly  Working_Hours/day

Comment: Well then you could write a procedure for that, i suggest nonetheless working with timestamps only

Comment: Timestamps make life easier